# Как сослаться на файл strings.xml при создании Toast?

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-toast

В втором параметре объекта Toast указывается текст уведомления. Как сослаться на файл strings.xml?

```java
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Всем привет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Вместо "Всем привет" сделать ссылку на strings.xml.

Comment: А учебник вам читать не приходилось? Как использовать ресурсы написано примерно во второй главе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ресурсы в Андроид (strings, drawables, layouts и т. д.) [можно получить](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Accessing), зная ID ресурса.

Все ID ресурсов определены в классе с именем `R`, который генерируется с помощью инструмента `aapt`.

Допустим, у вас есть строковый ресурс, определенный в файле **strings.xml**:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Привет</string>
</resources>
```

Тогда `aapt` сгенерирует следующий файл **R.class**:

```java
public final class R {
   ...
   public static final class string {
       ...
       public static final int hello = 1234;
   }
}
```

Таким образом, чтобы получить ID строки-ресурса, нужно обратиться к константе:

```java
R.string.hello
```

Answer (score 3):

У тебя есть `string.xml` в котором

```
<resources>
<string name="hello">Всем привет</string>
</resources>
```

И для того, чтобы вывести текст `Всем привет` с ключом `hello` нужно написать следующий код.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle args) {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String message = getString(R.string.hello);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();


}
```

Comment: Необязательно делать `getString(...)`, можно сразу передать `R.string.hello`.